# gulp foreach not iterating over all files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a function in my gulpfile as below.  However, it doesn't appear to be iterating over all the files in teh build directory.  I currently have `login.html` and `reset.html` in the buildDir folder, but it only ever iterates over login.html then exits.

Why won't it iterate over all the files?

```js
/**
 * Injects the contents of styles/{FILENAME,main}.css, scripts/{FILENAME,main}.js into FILENAME.html
 */
async function injectContents() {
    gulp.src(`${buildDir}/**/*.html`)
        .pipe(foreach((stream, chunk) => {
            console.log(chunk.path)
            gulp.src(chunk.path)
                .pipe(inject(gulp.src([`${buildDir}/styles/main.css`, `${buildDir}/styles/${path.basename(chunk.path, '.html')}.css`]), {
                    starttag: '<!-- inject:css -->',
                    removeTags: true,
                    transform: (filePath, file) => file.contents.toString('utf8')
                }))
                // TODO: Readd `-min`
                .pipe(inject(gulp.src([`${buildDir}/scripts/main.js`, `${buildDir}/scripts/${path.basename(chunk.path, '.html')}.js`]), {
                    starttag: '<!-- inject:js -->',
                    removeTags: true,
                    transform: (filePath, file) => file.contents.toString('utf8')
                }))
                .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(distDir))
        }))
}
```